# Calculating the induced emf without knowing the change in magnetic flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, induction

> 59. A conducting rod of length $\ell$ moves on two horizontal frictionless rails, as in Figure P20.30. A constant force of magnitude
>       1.00 N moves the bar at a uniform speed of 2.00 m/s through a magnetic field $B$ that is directed into the page. **(a)** What is the
>       current in an $8\Omega$ resistor $R$? **(b)** What is the rate of energy dissipation in the resistor? **(c)** What is the mechanical power delivered
>       by the constant force?
>
> College Physics 9th ed., Serway + Vuille, Chapter 20, Problem 59.

[image]

I'm having some trouble with calculating these values without knowing the magnitude of the magnetic field $B$ or the length $\ell$.

I'm trying to solve this problem using this equation:

$$\varepsilon = -N \frac {\Delta\phi_B} {\Delta t}$$

Which should give me the induced emf using the change in flux and the change in time. Since the conductor is moving at a constant speed, I can just take any two points in time and figure out the change in magnetic flux:

$$\Delta\phi_B = BA - B(A+2\ell) = -2B\ell$$

For this $\Delta\phi_B$, $\Delta t=1$. Plugging this into the first equation:

$$\varepsilon = -1 \frac {-2B\ell} 1 = 2B\ell$$

And since the resistance is $8\Omega$:

$$I = \frac {B\ell} 4$$

But how is it possible to know the emf without knowing the actual change in flux?

Comment: The problem expects you to engage on more than one level. You're doing fine employing Faraday's law, but you are also expected to deal with the problem in terms of energy.

Comment: @dmckee I'm still stumped. Does it have anything to do with the fact that there is a force of 1 N on the conductor? Is there some force opposing $\vec F_{app}$ that I'm not taking into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realize that for the conductor to be moving in a constant sepped, as you suggested in your comment, there must be a force opposing $\vec{F}_{app}$, that is the magnetic force $F_m=I\ell B$. Since the motion is uniform, both forces are equal, and you can then find the current. For the other questions, it's just the application of formulas, since you know all the necessarry values.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I appreciate it!